Can't use sdx tool together with Tclkit
I want to wrap my tcl program into single executable file and I reached tclkit and starkit.
I downloaded tclkit from here:
http://kitcreator.rkeene.org/kitcreator
I built it with next options: Linux/amd64, Packages: Metakit, Tcllib, Tk; Tcl8.6.12.
Then I run it and it works.
In next step I downloaded sdx tool in form of kit here:
https://chiselapp.com/user/aspect/repository/sdx/index
Then I open it with compiled tclkit and got:
can't find package vfs::mkcl
    while executing
"package require vfs::mkcl"
    (procedure "::vfs::mk4::Mount" line 4)
    invoked from within
"::vfs::mk4::Mount /home/georgtree/tclkit/sdx-20110317.kit /home/georgtree/tclkit/sdx-20110317.kit -readonly"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval [list ::vfs::${driver}::Mount $self $self] $args"

Trying to fix this I install vfs1.4.2 and vqtcl4.1. The last package provides this library (on screenshot) 
and I added this path to environmental variable, and...it doesn't work.
So my question is - what I did wrong and how to properly install all it.
My system is Kubuntu 22.04.
Thank you in advance, George.

Don’t run sdx using the tclkit. Use your system’s tclsh.

Hello, now there is another issue...
    attempt to provide package vfs::mkcl 1.10.1 failed: package vfs::mkcl 1.5 provided instead         ("package ifneeded vfs::mkcl 1.10.1" script)         invoked from within     "package require vfs::mkcl"         (procedure "::vfs::mk4::Mount" line 4)         invoked from within     "::vfs::mk4::Mount /home/georgtree/tclkit/sdx-20110317.kit /home/georgtree/tclkit/sdx-20110317.kit -readonly"         ("eval" body line 1)         invoked from within     "eval [list ::vfs::${driver}::Mount $self $self] $args"

You need to upgrade the vfs package (or get an older version of sdx). Sdx is asking for vfs::mkcl 1.10 and only getting 1.5, thus failing. It is possible (likely) that Kubuntu’s version is out of date. You may have to update it manually (see here). (Perhaps someone who knows better about this will show up and provide a better answer — give it a day or two.)

Yeah, I understand that, I installed this package manually, I think I need to find more modern version, thank you.

How exactly did you invoke sdx.kit? I have created a tclkit using the settings you indicated and it runs the sdx.kit without any issues. It's perfectly fine to run sdx using the tclkit. There is no need to use tclsh.

You didn't mention how you invoked sdx.kit. I used your link to create a tclkit with the same options you specified. I then downloaded the sdx.kit from the other link you provided. I also created a small tcl script called hello.tcl. I then performed the following steps:
chmod +x tclkit
mv sdx-20110317.kit sdx.kit
cp tclkit tclkit-rt
./tclkit sdx.kit qwrap hello.tcl -runtime tclkit-rt
./hello.kit

That runs the program as expected.
You can't have the same tclkit running sdx.kit and be included as the runtime. But a copy will do.
I did run this on SUSE Leap 15.6. But I don't expect that to be a factor, as the tclkit basically works on your system.

I do the same thing as you, and still get can't find package vfs::mkcl.
Also I can't find  vfs::mkcl 1.10.1 package online, only 1.5 version

I found sdx in form of executable, run it with hello.tcl, it works, but then I tried to open this hello.kit with tclkit, it shows the same error, I don't understand what I am doing wrong...
can't find package vfs::mkcl
while executing
"package require vfs::mkcl"
(procedure "::vfs::mk4::Mount" line 4)
invoked from within
"::vfs::mk4::Mount /home/george/tclkits/hello.kit /home/george/tclkits/hello.kit -readonly"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
"eval [list ::vfs::${driver}::Mount $self $self] $args"

Ok, it works, if I pack tclkit together with my script by using binary distribution of sdx: ./sdx qwrap ./hello.tcl -runtime tclkit_loc
